# Heroku assets for Twipsy and Tablesorter not working, locally yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I was wondering if anyone else ran into the problem where jQuery scripts such as Twipsy (from Twitter bootstrap) and Tablesorter work locally but not on Heroku.

Each time I cleaned my public/assets folder and precompiled for deployment environment.

The script actually shows up in the precompiled JS on heroku, but it doesn't seem to be recognized....

The weird part is that the first jQuery/Ajax function for the dropdown works fine on Heroku.

I use Rails 3.1 on heroku cedar stack

Here is my assets/application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.tablesorter.min
//= require bootstrap-twipsy
//= require bootstrap-alerts
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-popover
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy
//= require bootstrap-tabs


jQuery(function($) {
// when the #region_id field changes
  $("#contact_country_id").live('change', function() {
    // make a POST call and replace the content
    var country = $('select#contact_country_id :selected').val();
    if(country == "") country="0";
    jQuery.get('/countries/update_city_select/' + country, function(data){
        $("#cities").html(data);
    })
    return false;
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $("#sortTable").tablesorter({
        headers : {
            5: {
                sorter: false
            },
            8: {
                sorter: false
            },
            9: {
                sorter: false
            }
        },
        sortList: [[0,0]] 
    });
});

 jQuery(function($) {
  $('.action-icon').twipsy();
  $("a[rel=twipsy]").twipsy({
    live: true
  });
 });
//= require_tree .
```

Also changing the config assets made it work!

Your help would be most appreciated.

Aurelien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar problem.
Placing the bootstrap code before the line `//= require_tree .` solved this problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, but didn't change anything. When I run the Script console in Safari I get the following error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a("#sortTable").tablesorter({headers:{5:{sorter:!1},8:{sorter:!1},9:{sorter:!1}},sortList:[[0,0]]})')`. Maybe there is a problem with my code? Maybe the precompile is messing up the code?

Comment: Well perhaps a stupid comment but, make sure you are loading the jquery.tablesorter.js file (and the Twipsy js file) before you run the code that calls the tableSorter/twipsy functions.
I only mention this because I didn't see you loading the bootstrap/twipsy/tablesorter files (unless you have them living in the /assets/javascript and they get loaded with `//= require_tree .`
Additionally ensure you have this line `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in your config/application.rb. I also had to set `config.assets.compile = true` in config/enviroments/production.rb

Comment: Indeed all the js were in my assets files. What I did was to force call all the bootstrap and tablesorter file. Changed the config as you mentioned and re-precompiled the whole before pushing on the heroku server. It works! Thanks a lot!