# twitter bootstrap modals not working when pushed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap

The modals work locally, but when I push, they're not showing up. Not the ones where I have to click to show up, nor the ones that should show up automatically.

Has anybody ever had this issue?

```
<!-- modal window for explaining -->
<div class="modal fade center" id="self-b" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header center">
    <h3 style="font-weight:normal;">First things first</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#self-b').modal()
</script>
```

Comment: I would guess that there's a javascript problem, possibly that it isn't even there. Are there any errors in your browser console? Can you link to the site so we have a better chance of diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Answer on this thread:

[Heroku assets for Twipsy and Tablesorter not working, locally yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920836/heroku-assets-for-twipsy-and-tablesorter-not-working-locally-yes)

a gem got updated and inversed the order of loading js in appliaction.js. Putting require tree . at the end fixed it.